# can't view alternative languages when using django internationalization

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, localization, internationalization

I implememnting internationalization and localization in django

I have as a first test for Spanish, some simple text in a template:

```
{% load i18n %}
<h2>{% trans 'How It Works' %}</h2>
```

I have added the following to my settings:

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ca', _('Catalan')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)
```

I have generated the .po translation files with:

```
django-admin makemessages
```

I have created a sample translation with:

```
#: templates/index.html:112
msgid "How It Works"
msgstr "espanol test"
```

I have changed my chrome browser to use spanish language like according to:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#testing-mac

I would figure that when I go to my page that the "how it works" text would say "espanol test" but it does not.

**Am I doing something wrong to not render the translation?**

Answer (score 1):

I found that after you have created the translation with make-messages you have to run:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```